# Can we use 'undesirable' as an opposite of 'desirable' in the romantic meaning of the term?

Tags: word-choice

Considering the use of 'desirable' in a romantic sense to mean 'attractive' as in

> "She looks so desirable in that golden dress!"

is 'undesirable' appropriate to be used as antonym?

> She found him undesirable.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/undesirable

> undesirable
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not wanted or desirable because harmful, objectionable, or unpleasant.
> ‘the drug's undesirable side effects’

Although the above dictionary does list 'unpleasant' as a meaning, I wonder whether 'undesirable' is (not) a good choice of word to mean 'unattractive' or 'not desirable' in the romantic sense?

Edit: Based on the first answer,'undesirable' seems to be an example of a type of word that is constructed by adding a negative prefix to another word, but no longer serves as its most common antonym (Un + desirable = undesirable, but the most common antonym of desirable is now apparently 'unattractive') -- can members quote a few other examples?

Comment: I think it’s fine.  see: https://books.google.com/books?id=TUq0CAAAQBAJ&pg=PT236&dq=%22make+her+undesirable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj03-vm-szTAhVJ02MKHYLbCUUQ6AEIKzAD

Comment: Or here: https://books.google.com/books?id=EZJScj5Zg5IC&pg=PA104&dq=%22make+her+undesirable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj03-vm-szTAhVJ02MKHYLbCUUQ6AEIMDAE

Comment: I would be careful with "undesirable."  An undesirable person is usually someone you don't want to be around, so in that sense it is an antonym, but if you just mean "someone who I don't desire," it's probably too strong, and I would stick with eup's advice and use "unattractive."  That would imply no romantic attraction, but not necessarily an active *dislike* of the person.

Comment: Thank you @Jim for posting some good examples where 'undesirable' is used in the sense of 'unattractive.' Is it true that the 'more common' meaning of undesirable as 'troublesome' inhibits its use in the 'unattractive ' sense to avoid being misinterpreted?

Comment: it all comes down to context.  In the proper context it will not be misinterpreted.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime I did note that 'unattractive' is used far more often in this context, and have edited my question to add a query about words that have been constructed by adding negative suffix to other words but no longer serve as the 'most common' antonyms.

Comment: I don't think *desirable* has romantic connotations, so the question does not have a firm footing.

Comment: @Clare can you clarify how 'desirable' as used in "she looked so desirable in that gold dress" (which I actually read this week in an online magazine referring to a movie star at a film festival) does 'not' have romantic connotations? If you mean 'undesirable' does not have romantic connotations then I can certainly agree, based on these answers and comments.

Comment: Maybe we need to define *romantic*. It is not the same as *erotic*, which to me is the type of thing that calling someone  *desirable* belongs to.

Comment: @Clare Now I get it -- unfortunately 'romantic' is used as a catch-all broad spectrum term in India and, in many cases, probably employed in a sense to mean 'erotic' which is rarely used -- thanks for clarifying the fine difference!

Comment: @Clare Similar to 'romantic' for 'erotic', the word 'glamour' is also routinely misused in India to really mean 'exploitative' as applied to movies and other media. Do these 2 examples  qualify as 'excessively polite usage,' 'prudish', hypocritical' or 'euphemism'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Unattractive' would be more often used than 'undesirable' if you are talking about a person. 'Undesirable' is more often used to describe an outcome or situation or result.

If you were to go so far as to say 'undesirable' about a person in a romantic sense, it would be better to add to it:

- Totally undesirable
- Completely undesirable
- Utterly undesirable, and so on.

Comment: See the quotes in comments above.  I don’t think it’s as clear cut as this.

Comment: I would distinguish between *She found him unattractive* and *She did not find him attractive*. The former conveys something different from and stronger than the latter.

Comment: @RichardKayser yes indeed it does -- just as 'unattractive' is different from 'not attractive' it seems 'undesirable' (as in, she found him undesirable) is very different from 'not + desirable' (as in, she did **not** find him desirable) it seems that 'not attractive' and 'not desirable' have 'neutral tone' in this context.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Exactly. I am fond of the difference between *significant* and *not insignificant* and similar distinctions. They're graded and useful. Two negatives often do not equal a positive.

Comment: @Richard Kayser Even without using devices like adverbs or modifiers for emphasis or mitigation, there seems to be a natural 'scale of continuum' from negative through neutral to positive as in unattractive--not unattractive--not attractive--attractive. Such options are given in questionnaires, etc used for collecting user feedback, and for studies in the social sciences. I agree with you that proper use of such terms even in general English helps us to precisely express what we mean, without creating scope for ambiguity and misinterpretation.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Good point. Here's another when it comes to girls: interested versus uninterested versus not disinterested!

Comment: @RichardKayser English has so many shades of meaning even for common terms -- not expensive / not inexpensive -- as to well and truly confound the non native speaker! In the above scale, 'not unattractive' is commonly interpreted as 'slightly attractive' or 'rather attractive' and therefore distinct in meaning from 'not attractive' which is 'more neutral' -- so I think being very specific as in 'she found him neither attractive nor unattractive' is the only way to be  'perfectly neutral'!

Comment: @Richard Kayser and Clare -- Indians are similarly confused with understatements such as 'not bad' when used to mean 'good', 'quite good' and even 'very good' -- when I was in school 25 years back, a leading student once recited a perfect answer and the English teacher, who was a fan of British expressions, said 'not bad!' which led to much confusion till he explained that 'not bad' in that context was used to mean 'very good!'